# An inequality involving $e$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality, stochastic-differential-equations

Context: [Introduction to SDEs, by Evans](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d66c/a1516e1a9a9247f94841ccfbb262cf26d5e4.pdf), page 43, proof of Lemma 3.

The author writes

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-s^2/2}\mathrm{d}s\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/4}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-s^2/4}\mathrm{d}s.$$

Why does this inequality hold? What does it follow from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $s\geq x$ then 
$$e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}}e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}}\leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}}$$
and the result follows by multiplying both sides by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and integrating.